# Pass-through authentication tokens from session to external services

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using Node as basically a stateless data aggregation tier.

It's a rather "deep" implementation in that I'm not just calling direct from express route handlers to an external server, the process flows through the "controller" which calls into a "provider" which calls into a "service" layer which needs the session data to make the request to the other servers.

Is there any crafty way to get the `req.session` info at the "service" layer again, without passing it backwards to every layer in-between?  The session plumbing bothers me for some reason.